# Displaying report, failed to decode downloaded font

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I had CORS problem when I'm displaying icCube report embeded in my angular app, via Javascript explicit authentication. I solved CORS problem with adding node server as proxy.
New problem is(in javascript console):

> Failed to decode downloaded font: htp://localhost:3000/icCube/doc/ic3-report/app/lib/glyphicons/fonts/glyphicons-regular.woff

and

> OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Because of these errors(there is about twenty same errors), my report doesn't look like original report in icCube. Some things are broken.

Look of report: http://prntscr.com/en27pc

Comment: To avoid this problems you should put the angular app and icCube in the same domain, we do not advise this kind of setups for a production environment

Comment: What do you mean by that? They are both on same host, currently 'localhost', but on different ports. They can't be on the same port.

Comment: Domain includes also the port. They should both be behind a web server, or icCube behind a proxy in the angular app (we need this for later to add authentication/authorization)

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem as @ic3 suggested, I set up Apache as main entry point for my app and icCube server. Thanks.